# Error: Class MigrationShell could not be loaded (Cakephp -3.0 )

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.0 and i am facing problem while installing migration plugin..i am following the steps mentioned below

**Installation - First get the plugin!**

```
$:~/public_html/cakephp3/myCakeApp/plugins$ git clone git://github.com/CakeDC/migrations.git
```

**Add the following to app/Config/bootstrap.php**

```
CakePlugin::load('Migrations');
```

now next installation part is given in documentation as(may be this part may work for cakephp 2.x)

```
$ app/Console/cake
Available Shells:
migration [Migrations]
```

i am not getting this part and also don't know how to load MigrationShell in cakephp 3.. Can anybody help me out please??

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3 comes with its own migrations plugin. Create a fresh CakePHP 3 project and you will be able to execute `bin/cake migrations`

You can read the documentation of the official migrations plugin in this page:

https://github.com/cakephp/migrations